# System.Object[] can't be converted to System.String[]

Tags: c#, vb.net, migration

I'm trying to convert the C# line

```
string[] phrases = text.Split (new[] { '\"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

to VB.NET.

My attempt was

```
Dim phrases() As String = text.Split (New Object() { """"c }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

However, I'm getting the error "System.Object[] can't be converted to System.String[]".

What I'm doing wrong, please?

Comment: [String.Split Method (Char(), StringSplitOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm not that fluent in VB, but it seems like the `New Object()` part is the problem as it would be instantiating the values in the new array as `Object`s rather than `String`s.

Comment: @Abion47: No, the OP is using the overload that takes a char array - that's why they are passing a char array (not a string array) in the C# version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use any online C# to VB converter and you'll get this:

```
Dim phrases As String() = text.Split(New String() {""""C}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

So the wrong part was using Object().

Comment: Thanks, but your code produces the error "Type expected".

Comment: Try `New String()` instead.

Comment: Yes, that did it. But Daniel needs to edit his answer, please.

Comment: You're thinking of C# - VB either wants the type or leave out the 'new'.  You need to know the languages to make a converter.

Answer (score -1):

As Plutonix mentioned in his comment, the first parameter is a char array (new[] { '\"' } is nothing if not a char array), so perhaps it makes some sense to use a char array?

```
Dim phrases() As String = text.Split(New Char() {""""c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Now in VB, you don't even need to say 'New Char()', since VB knows that {""""c} is a char array:

```
Dim phrases() As String = text.Split({""""c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```